# Password changing code error

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I am using `password_hash` function, it work's well in registration form and login form but doesn't work during change password form, it gives me error message incorrect old password may be my code has gone wrong or may be because `password_hash` generates different set of characters each time even with the same input, if it is so what method is used to update password. the same code works using md5.

```
if(isset($_POST['senddata'])){
    $old_password = $_POST['oldpassword'];
    $new_password = $_POST['newpassword'];
    $repeat_password = $_POST['newpassword2'];    

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db_password=$row['password'];
    // hash old password before match
    $old_password = password_hash($old_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    // check if old password equals db_password
    if ($old_password==$db_password) {
        // continue changing users password
        if ($new_password==$repeat_password) {
            // hash the new password
            $new_password=password_hash($new_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $repeat_password=password_hash($repeat_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            // update password
            $password_update_query=$db->prepare("UPDATE userss SET password=:password, password2=:password2 WHERE username=:username");
            $password_update_query->execute(array(':password'=>$new_password,':password2'=>$repeat_password2,':username'=>$username));
            echo "Your Password Updated";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Old password is incorrect";
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump` variables and compare. Check what `password_hash` option you use during registration.

Comment: you are not getting `$username` from your post!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [password_verify($password, $hash);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for verifying that passwords are equal

When you hash it again you get a other result because it generates a new salt, which then result in an other hash.

Something like:

```
$old_password = $_POST['oldpassword'];
$db_password = $row['password']; // which should be already hashed
if (password_verify($old_password, $db_password) {
```